# Two subspaces $A$, $B$ are paralel, if and only if they are both subspaces of a space with a dimension equal $d = 1 + \max (\dim A, \dim B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is true, that two affine subspaces $A$, $B$ are paralel, if and only if there exists an affine space $C$, that both are subspaces of $C$, and $\dim C = 1 + \max (\dim A, \dim B)$?

If so, do You have a proof?

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you mean *affine* subspaces.

Well, the statement is *not true*: consider for example any two lines as $A$ and $B$ intersecting in a point, then they satisfy your criterium, as they generate the plane of those intersecting lines, though the lines are not parallel.

Another example is $A:=$ plane $(z=0)$, $B:=$ $z$-axis.

However, if in addition $A\cap B=\emptyset$ is assumed, then we can conclude that $A\parallel B$, as follows:

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\dim A\ge\dim B$ and that $0\in A$ (else we can shift both sets with $-a_0$ for any fixed $a_0\in A$). Then, let $b_0\in B$ arbitrary. By assumption, $b_0\notin A$, so for the generated (now linear) subspace $W:=\langle A,b_0\rangle=\{a+rb_0\,\mid\, r\in\Bbb R,\ a\in A\}$, we have
$$\dim W = 1+\dim A=1+\max(\dim A,\dim B)$$
So, that $W=\langle A,B\rangle$ by hypothesis. This means that for any $b\in B$, we have $b=a+rb_0$. I let it for you to check that if $r\ne 1$, then the line of $b_0$ and $b$ will intersect $A$, which case is excluded.

So, we have $r=1$ and $b-b_0\in A$, meaning that the vector from $b_0$ to $b$ is parallel to $A$. -QED-

Comment: I'm worried, that I've made a mistake in question. In this case, because there exist an space that have bigger dimension and both paralel lines are contained in it. So the statement is true in this case

Comment: I have updated just now, your claim is true, provided $A$ and $B$ are *disjoint*.